# Access imagebutton src in postback

Tags: asp.net, src, imageurl

Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community, ASP.NET v4.8 web application project using VB.NET

Problem: I have an asp imagebutton which is used to indicate a status by changing the image each time it is clicked (red-amber-green-red).  This is done using javascript:

`btn.src = newImage;`

This works fine.  The imageurl is accessed using src in the html but the image is initially set in the code behind databind by setting the imagebutton.imageurl:

`btn.ImageUrl = initialImage`

On a postback (a save) I want to find the status by looking at the current imageurl.

```
Dim btn As ImageButton = CType(mainGrid.Rows(i).FindControl("btn"), ImageButton))
```

`someval = btn.imageurl`

The problem is that imageurl shows the value initially set, not the changed value.  This weirdness seems to point to a bug in my code somewhere as obviously the imagebutton variable in the save code behind knows nothing about the imagebutton variable in the databind code behind.

Can someone confirm that imageurl in the postback should in fact match the changed src in the html?

Edit:  I should say that I don't want to use server-side processing each time they click the imagebutton.  I can make this work using a command argument BUT that leads to a database write every time they click.  There are a dozen or so buttons on each row so I think that would be pretty slow in production.

Comment: Image controls don't have a automatic view state like say a text box does. So you can set/change say a text box in client side js - and on post back the value will persist and can be seen + used by code behind. For a image control? Unfortantly while you can set it in client side js code - the setting does not persist on post back. This means/suggests that you have to save the changed value in a array, or set some extra column in the grid that saves this value. Or put the whole grid in a up-date panel, and simply use code behind for this setting.

Comment: Ok Albert I understand.  I'll try an update panel approach.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Either that, have a hidden column, and change both src, and that extra column. With a update panel, you don't get a full post-back, and often performance + response is quite good. But, if you going all out - then when you change the src for the image, then save that into hidden field - but since your using src as your "flag" for information, then you probably best just change some value (such as 1,2,3) or whatever, and also change the src  for the image - in other words, don't use our non persisting URL as the means to determine the choice made. So you can still do this - or update panel

Comment: Also a good suggestion - thanks again.  I looked at the update panel approach and the whole page is one gridview with dozens of these changing indicators so I thought that route would be little different to posting the whole thing back.  I ended up using jquery.post to do an async ajax update to the db on each change, which works well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, provided by Albert D. Kallal, is that imagebuttons don't pass any changed attributes back to the code behind.  Possible solutions are to 1) use an update panel, 2) change a paired hidden field at the same time (of a type that does pass the change back) or 3) use ajax to update the db after the change.  I used option 3.